# Can a SQL Server Feature Pack of a certain version (2012, 2016, etc.) be used with a lower version of SQL Server?

Tags: .net, sql-server, clr, sqlclr

My company is in the process of upgrading the SQL Server CLR types that are being used with our software. After Googling around, I couldn't find a definitive yes/no answer to whether or not the SQL Server Feature Pack version can be greater than the version of SQL Server that's deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current release vehicle for that is NuGet, https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.  And this client-side package doesn't have any version dependency on the server-side version.

Comment: Okay, thank you! That takes care of one DLL upon which we rely. I also found out that we use SQLServerSpatial somewhere, and I know that that also comes from the SQL Feature Packs. Didn't see that one in NuGet. Does that one also not have a version dependency with SQL Server?